# How come my simple insertion is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to test a simple insertion before going full-fledged.
However, no matter what I tried, it just wouldn't work out.

Some background about the form.
The form contains labels which are auto-populated with data, some that required users to enter themselves.  I am just using 3 simple variables to test things out.  Now, even if I embed the sql directly, the data doesn't enter into database.

```
        internal void UpdateEPMTRequest2(string EPMTNumber, string name, int status)
    {
        con.Open();
        //  var sql = "INSERT INTO EPMT_MASTER_REQUEST (EPMTID, , Status) values (@ePMTNumber, @name, @status)";

        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Exec[ePMT_SP_UpdateEPMTRequest2] '2', 'Tanagara', 0");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ePMT_SP_UpdateEPMTRequest2", con);            
      //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", action);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ePMTNumber", EPMTNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

      private void UpdateEPMTRequest2(string EPMTNumber, string name, int status)
    {
        try
        {
            eBiz.UpdateEPMTRequest2(EPMTNumber, name, status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

   internal void UpdateEPMTRequest2(string EPMTNumber, string name, int status)
    {
        eDAO.UpdateEPMTRequest2(EPMTNumber, name, status);
    }
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["EPMTID"] != null)
        {
            string Action = "SaveUpdate";
            string EPMTNumber = Request.QueryString["EPMTID"].ToString();
            int status = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CStatus"].ToString());
           // UpdateEPMTRequest(Action, EPMTNumber, status);
            Response.Redirect("ePMTDraft.aspx?msg=1");
        }
        else
        {
            //  string Action = "Save";

            if (Request.QueryString["EPMTID"] == null)
                if (status == 0)
                    try
                    {                       
                    EPMTNumber = Request.QueryString["EPMTID"].ToString();
                    // UpdateEPMTRequest(Action, EPMTNumber, status);
                    UpdateEPMTRequest2(EPMTNumber, name, status);
                      }
                     catch (Exception ex) { }
                    Response.Redirect("ePMTDraft.aspx?msg=1");
                }
            }

      ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ePMT_SP_UpdateEPMTRequest2]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ePMTNumber varchar(20),
@name varchar(100),     
@status int
```

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO EPMT_MASTER_REQUEST (EPMTID, IssuerName, status) values (@ePMTNumber, @name, @status)
```

END

The name in this case is a auto-populated field which has a session value which I do not know if session value should be used instead of the string name.

Another problem is that the name is giving me an error - not found in context.  The name is actually for a label lblInititor.text.

Comment: You need to tell us your connection string (change any password), and to remove `catch (Exception ex) { }`.

Comment: I have left out the connection string. but if you want to see the insert statement I can add it in

Comment: Empty catch block is really dangerous and that's where you are stuck and not able to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Chetan, the problem is that for this code that I am using, there is no value objects being used but if I remove the try catch, then the Visual Studio is going to scream "NullReference" exception - Object reference not set to an instance of an object..  What should I do then?

Comment: anyway, I have overcome this NullReference exception by adding this line  if (EPMTNumber == null) { 
                        EPMTNumber = Request.QueryString["EPMTID"].ToString();  But, the data is not not being passed to the database

Answer (score 0):

In the commented code of sql statement number of columns and number of values to INSERT do not match.

If you are using the same statement in the storwd proc then that might be tha cause of error.

If you debug and see the exception details you should be able to see the error.

You need to change the insert statement as following.

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO EPMT_MASTER_REQUEST (EPMTID, Name, Status) values (@ePMTNumber, @name, @status)";
```

I am not sure of the exact column name of the table so I assumed it to be "Name".

If this works the you need to use the same query in the stored proc too.

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Chetan, the column name is IssuerName but even I have changed that in my cs code, the data doesn't get inserted.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Did you observe the message of the exception? Are you sure you are pointing to the correct data base in the code and checking the same database to verify if the data inserted ?

Comment: I am very sure the database connection is correct.  Is there any other way I can test things out like even a simpler way ?

Comment: Debugging is the only way to figureout what's going wrong. Did you debug the code? Does it go inside the method `internal void UpdateEPMTRequest2` or simply skipping it because value of status is not zero?

Comment: I put a breakpoint below my button save and it only goes to the EPMTNumber inside the UpdateEPMTRequest2 
and it skips reading the name and status.  What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error? Does it go to catch block?

Comment: It does not gives me any exception error.  I think let me post the full save event code so that you are more clear bout how the whole save events look like.  After it read the EPMTNumber, it just jump out of it and it never read the other 2 parameters inside.

Comment: you mean it reaches to ` cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ePMTNumber", EPMTNumber);` and then jumps out of it ? If yes then it should jump to `catch (Exception ex) { }` in `btnSave_Click`. Am I right?

Comment: No.  The code didn't even go to my DAO class where the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue lies....and it did not jump to catch Exception.  This discussion is getting too long.  Should I create another new thread?

Comment: Does it reach to `EPMTNumber = Request.QueryString["EPMTID"].ToString();` ? Does it reach to ` eDAO.UpdateEPMTRequest2(EPMTNumber, name, status);` did you put breakpoint in DAO method?  Better we discuss on the chat..

Comment: Sorry Chetan, there was a down time in my company's internet.  What is a good time I can chat with you about this issue ? N tks so much for helping me.